# Delphi with Indy 9: What is the newest version of openssl dlls that can be used?

Tags: delphi

In our environment, we are finding that the newest openssl dlls we can use from this source:

http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/

are from 2004.

Is there an update to indy9, or other magic, that can help us get to something newer than 2004?

Thank you!

Comment: What about an upgrade to Indy 10 ?

Comment: @TLama for some of our code, an indy10 upgrade is too much surgery.

Comment: Indy 9 requires custom OpenSSL DLLs (more specifically, custom functions added to OpenSSL). There is no getting around that without re-writing Indy 9 to remove those dependencies. If you want to make an effort to update the latest OpenSSL to export the necessary Indy-specific functions, or update Indy 9 to not need them anymore, go for it. Indy 9 is no longer in development, so I'm not going to spend time updating it to work with the latest OpenSSL. Indy 10 already does that, and I'm trying to get Indy 10 to a point where it can sit for awhile so we can start work on Indy 11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau We are prob going to jump to indy 10. We have it working in our client now, no problem. In the server piece.... bigger job.

Comment: Using OpenSSL libraries from 2004 is simply asking for trouble. Better hope that you don't have anything internet facing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan None of this is inet facing. It is very limited use. Anyway, we have made the decision to move to indy10 across the board.

Comment: for those who have to stay with Indy9 theres an experimental package with higher OpenSSL:
https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/Experimental/